# what does lapply(Output_data,"[[",2) mean in R

Tags: r, lapply

In RHadoop, when we make the results readable, it will use the code:

```
results <- data.frame(words=unlist(lapply(Output_data,"[[",1)), count
=unlist(lapply(Output_data,"[[",2)))
```

but what does `lapply(Output_data,"[[",1)`mean? especially the "[[" and '1' in lapply.

Comment: This question does not have to do anything with `rhadoop`, removing the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of extracting `list` elements with `[` or `[[` is often used in `R`.  It is not specific to any packages.  The meaning of the syntax

```
lapply(Output_data,"[[",1)
```

is loop through the object 'Output_data' and extract (`[[`) the first element.  So, if the 'Output_data' is a `list` of `data.frame`s, it will extract the first column of the `data.frame` and if it is a `list` of `vector`s, it extracts the first elements of `vector`.  It does similar functionality as an anonymous function does i..e

```
lapply(Output_data, function(x) x[[1]])
```

The latter syntax is more clear and easier to understand but the former is compact and a bit more stylish...

More info about the `[[` can be found in `?Extract`

Answer (score 1):

Operators like `[[` , `[` and `->` are actually functions.

```
list[[1]]
```

is equal to

```
`[[`(list,1)
```

In your case, `lapply(Output_data,"[[",1)`means to extract the first value of every column (or sublist) of `Output_data`. And the `1` is a argument passed to `[[` function.